# What should output of tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, conda

I installed `tensorflow-gpu` via `conda install tensorflow-gpu`.

However, the computer I installed on doesn't have a GPU.  I did this b/c I'm porting a conda env to an offline computer.

When I `import tensorflow as tf` and call `tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()` the results is `False`.  Even though the computer doesn't have a GPU, I was expecting the result to be `True` because I instal
led tensorflow-gpu.
What should output of tf.test.is_built_with_cuda() be in this case?

Why do I get `False`?

Answer (score 3):

I just tested this with a server that previously was running a CUDA GPU, but then had the GPU removed - a fairly similar scenario to yours. I have `tensorflow-gpu==2.5.0` installed.

```py
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2021-07-28 18:42:44.236258: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
>>> tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()
True
```

A similar issue was documented [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47147). Therefore, you are most likely lacking CUDA/CUDNN.

Comment: Was tensorflow installed using `conda install tensorflow-gpu` while there was a GPU on the machine?

Comment: This is w/o conda - just pip. It should not matter - though yes, I do believe tensorflow-gpu was installed while there was a GPU in the machine. I don't have the ability to test otherwise.